# QGIS GUI: How to get independant windows?

Tags: gui, qgis-2.4

I am working with the georeferencer plugin, and I would like to have it working in fully independent windows.

Is it possible ?

Thanks for your help.

*Context:*

I am working with qgis 2.4 under Ubuntu 12.04.

I spot a dock/undock button on the top right corner of the plugin window. 
However even when undock is pressed, the windows remains linked to the qgis window and cannot be moved freely or displayed in full screen.

---

Here is as overview of the windows layout
[image: Windows Overview]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you need to do is go to Georeferencer menu "Settings/configure georeferencer" (English version). Then, a window pops up - uncheck "Show georeferencer window docked" on the bottom of the window. I have only access to Windows version, but it should be the same in Ubuntu.

Comment: Great, it works. My mistake was to look at the settings is QGIS, whereas the settings are inside the Georeferencer plugin (Keyboard shortcut Ctrl+P)

Comment: I tried this shortcut, but it does not work while the window is in docked state. Is it the same on Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, same behavior on Ubuntu. I guess the shortcut it blocked by qgis desktop before reaching georeferencer. Thank for your help anyway.